# How to supply a value of a server in NFS mount in a k8 Deployment via a ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap, mounted-volumes

I'm writing a helm chart where I need to supply a `nfs.server` value for the volume mount from the `ConfigMap` (**efs-url** in the example below).

There are examples in the docs on how to pass the value from the `ConfigMap` to env variables or even mount `ConfigMaps`. I understand how I can pass this value from the `values.yaml` but I just can't find an example on how it can be done using a `ConfigMap`.

I have control over this `ConfigMap` so I can reformat it as needed.

1. Am I missing something very obvious?
2. Is it even possible to do?
3. If not, what are the possible workarounds?

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: efs-url
data:
  url: yourEFSsystemID.efs.yourEFSregion.amazonaws.com

---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: efs-provisioner
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: efs-provisioner
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: efs-provisioner
          image: quay.io/external_storage/efs-provisioner:latest
          env:
            - name: FILE_SYSTEM_ID
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: efs-provisioner
                  key: file.system.id
            - name: AWS_REGION
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: efs-provisioner
                  key: aws.region
            - name: PROVISIONER_NAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: efs-provisioner
                  key: provisioner.name
          volumeMounts:
            - name: pv-volume
              mountPath: /persistentvolumes
      volumes:
        - name: pv-volume
          nfs:
            server:  <<< VALUE SHOULD COME FROM THE CONFIG MAP >>>
            path: /
```

Comment: You can only use ConfigMap values to set environment variables or to inject files into the pod; you can't use them to configure general settings in the YAML file.  Does it _need_ to be a ConfigMap?  Have you looked at tools like Helm or Customize which allow you to template or modify the YAML in various ways?

Comment: We had one specific use case where ConfigMaps would fit nicely. We do use Helm and Kustomize(via Flux), so we came up with a workaround. It's a pity tough that CF didn't work out.

Comment: @ValeraManiuk does the above comment solve your issue?

Comment: It does in a sense that we won't pursue that avenue, and instead use some workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having analysed the comments it looks like using ConfigMap approach is not suitable for this example as ConfigMap

> is an API object used to store non-confidential data in key-value pairs. Pods can consume ConfigMaps as environment variables, command-line arguments, or as configuration files in a volume.

To read more about ConfigMaps and how they can be utilized one can visit the ["ConfigMaps" section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) and the ["Configure a Pod to Use a ConfigMap" section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).